# cgi script file showing code in browser instead of running

Tags: python

My cgi script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

reshtml='''Content-Type:text/html\n
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>
Friends CGI demo(dynamic screen)
</title>
</HEAD>
<body>
<h3>Friends list for:<i>%s</i></h3>
Your name is: <b>%s</b>
You have<b>%s</b>friends.
</body>
</HTML>'''

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
who = form['person'].value
howmany = form['howmany'].value
print(reshtml % (who, who, howmany))
```

here server returns full script as a text in place of executing it and according to me it should return only reshtml value which is understandable to browser. 
I am using python web server and executing command C:\Python32\Lib\http\server.py successfully in current working directory. 
So what is the problem going on here?

Comment: What do u need in server detail... i am new in this field so plz elaborate. And few of the information is already mention in question.

Answer (score 0):

The default http server from that module does not include CGI support. If you have Python3.4, perhaps you are missing the `--cgi` switch to http/server:

```
c:\> python c:\python32\lib\http\server.py --cgi
```

or, more conveniently :

```
c:\> python -mhttp.server --cgi
```

On the other hand, if you hgave Python3.2, try the following, which should work in both environments:

Create a file called httpd.py:

```
import http.server

server_address = ('',8000)
server_class = http.server.HTTPServer
handler_class = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Run it like so:

```
c:\> python \httpd.py
```

It will serve executable CGI files correctly, but only if they are located in `./cgi-bin/` or `./htbin/`.

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: But it is giving error F:\NISHANT_WORK>python c:\python32\lib\http\server.py --cgi Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\python32\lib\http\server.py", line 1186, in <module> test(HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) File "c:\python32\lib\http\server.py", line 1168, in test port = int(sys.argv[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '--cgi'

Comment: The command-line args to the http.server module changed between Python3.2 (what you have) and Python3.4 (what I have). Try the script I've provided above.

Comment: thanks rob server is running now but the main problem still exist...script return as a text in place of executing it.

Comment: Perhaps your script is not located in `http://server:port/cgi-bin/script.py`. If it, for example, listed in `http://server:port/some-other-folder/script.py`, it will not execute.

Comment: can u explain me the structure and steps which i should follow to execute my script. I have my cgi-bin folder in F drive where I have my httpd.py on executing it server is running up. But when i execute some action on html page which is at F:\friends.html It should execute my cgi script (which is in cgi-bin folder let say friends.py) but it is returning text.